# How to fill in missing months in an array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a way how can i complete missing month and sale in an incomplete array.

sometimes i get a query like this:

```
var sales = [

    {'month': '04', 'sale': 126},
    {'month': '06', 'sale': 165},
    {'month': '07', 'sale': 10},
    {'month': '08', 'sale': 20},
    {'month': '09', 'sale': 211},
    {'month': '10', 'sale': 27},
    {'month': '11', 'sale': 112},
];
```

and i need to add the missing months with sale: 0.

I thought i can make a second array with all months and then compare this two arrays and pick the duplicates to the array with all months:

```
var compareArray = [

    {'month': '01', 'sale': 0},
    {'month': '02', 'sale': 0},
    {'month': '03', 'sale': 0},
    {'month': '04', 'sale': 0},
    {'month': '05', 'sale': 0},
    {'month': '06', 'sale': 0},
    {'month': '07', 'sale': 0},
    {'month': '08', 'sale': 0},
    {'month': '09', 'sale': 0},
    {'month': '10', 'sale': 0},
    {'month': '11', 'sale': 0},
    {'month': '12', 'sale': 0},
];
```

Comment: Make an array such that the month number is the index into that array, and then fill in the empty slots with new 0-sale objects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of pre-defining the 12-entries array, you could use `Array(12).keys()` and use `Array.from` to map that to the desired output:

```js
var sales = [{'month': '04', 'sale': 126}, {'month': '06', 'sale': 165}, {'month': '07', 'sale': 10},  {'month': '08', 'sale': 20}, {'month': '09', 'sale': 211}, {'month': '10', 'sale': 27}, {'month': '11', 'sale': 112}];

sales = Array.from(Array(12).keys(), month => 
    sales.find(sale => +sale.month === month+1) || { month: ("0"+(month+1)).substr(-2), sale: 0 }
);

console.log(sales);
```

Comment: I was surprised to see the .from - My ES6 is shaky when it comes to arrows

Comment: `[...Array(12)].map` also saves the from

Comment: It saves the `from`, but it creates an extra array before the `map` happens. The `Array.from` callback mechanism avoids the creation of that intermediate array.

Comment: There would be nothing to `map` then, @mplungjan: there are no entries in `Array(12)`, just a `length`.

Comment: `[...Array(12)]` could be mapped

Comment: Yes, @dhilt, that was already suggested above: see my reply to that.

Comment: I wanted to try something like `sales.push(...Array(12-sales.length).fill({month:0, sale:0}))`  but gave up

Answer (score 3):

An approach based on .map and .find array methods

```
const data = [
    {'month': '04', 'sale': 126},
    {'month': '06', 'sale': 165},
    {'month': '07', 'sale': 10},
    {'month': '08', 'sale': 20},
    {'month': '09', 'sale': 211},
    {'month': '10', 'sale': 27},
    {'month': '11', 'sale': 112},
];

const result = [...Array(12)].map((m, i) => {
  const month = i < 9 ? '0' + (i + 1) : String(i + 1);
  return data.find(d => d.month === month) || { month, sale: 0 };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `for` loop then `Array.sort()` to get the desired output:

```js
var sales = [{
    'month': '04',
    'sale': 126
  },
  {
    'month': '06',
    'sale': 165
  },
  {
    'month': '07',
    'sale': 10
  },
  {
    'month': '08',
    'sale': 20
  },
  {
    'month': '09',
    'sale': 211
  },
  {
    'month': '10',
    'sale': 27
  },
  {
    'month': '11',
    'sale': 112
  },
];
for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
  var existObj = sales.find(item => +item.month === i);
  if (!existObj) {
    sales.push({
      'month': i > 9 ? i : '0' + i,
      'sale': 0
    });
  }
}
sales.sort(function(a, b) {
  return +a.month - +b.month;
});
console.log(sales);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your month numbers *are* numbers, and span a convenient range, you can use them as array indexes:

```
var yearSales = sales.reduce(function(rv, month) {
  a[parseInt(month.month, 10)] = month;
  return a;
}, []);
```

Then you can find the empty slots:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++)
  if (!yearSales[i])
    yearSales[i] = { month: i, sales: 0 };
```

(I didn't use `.forEach()` because it skips empty slots, and those are the ones I want to target.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same approach I used below. Bascially just loop 1 - 12 and if you find missing months, add them to the array. Once you have all your months in the array, simply sort in ascending order based on month number.

```js
const sales = [{
    'month': '04',
    'sale': 126
  },
  {
    'month': '06',
    'sale': 165
  },
  {
    'month': '07',
    'sale': 10
  },
  {
    'month': '08',
    'sale': 20
  },
  {
    'month': '09',
    'sale': 211
  },
  {
    'month': '10',
    'sale': 27
  },
  {
    'month': '11',
    'sale': 112
  }
];

function generateSalesReport(salesData) {
  const monthsWithSales = [];
  const salesReport = [];
  salesData.forEach(el => {
    monthsWithSales.push(Number.parseInt(el.month));
    salesReport.push(el);
  });

  //Fill in the missing months
  for (let i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    if (monthsWithSales.indexOf(i) === -1) {
      let monthStr = i.toString();
      salesReport.push({
        'month': monthStr.length < 2 ? '0' + monthStr : monthStr,
        'sale': 0
      });
    }
  }

  //Sort the sales report array
  return salesReport.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a.month) - parseInt(b.month));
}

console.log(generateSalesReport(sales));
```